# What causes a low coolent temp light to come on a 2012 Honda civic

Tags: honda, electrical, civic, coolant, temperature

My 2012 Honda civic with 19,000 miles has a blue temp light on dash and it seems to be running fine?

Comment: I'm sorry, Scott, was there a real question in there? You may want to flesh your question out a little more with what you've discovered about it and what you've tried to do to remedy the situation. Also, depending on when you bought it, your Civic should still have a warranty on it.

Comment: Does it go off after a while, or does it come on after a while?

Answer (score 3):

Check your coolant level and keep an eye on your temperature gauge. A car will run fine with an overheating engine right up to the point when the engine seizes.

Comment: My research suggests that the 2012 Civic is not equipped with a temperature gauge, so that advice may not be useful.

Comment: Substitute "gauge" for "light".

Comment: I think the issue is that the *low* temperature light may indicate a problem with the temperature sensor, in which case the *high* temperature light would not work.

Comment: So have we figured out whether the low, or high, light is burning?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [owner's manual](http://owners.honda.com/vehicles/information/2012/Civic-Sedan/manuals), the 2012 Civic doesn't have a traditional temperature gauge.  Instead, there is a light (a thermometer and an H) to indicate that the temperature is too high and the car is overheating (meaning you should pull over before you damage the engine), and another light (a thermometer and a C) to indicate that the temperature is apparently too low.  It sounds like you are talking about the second one (the manual doesn't say what color it is, but blue would make sense).

Note the word "apparently".  It seems unlikely that the coolant would actually be cold after driving for a few minutes, so a more likely scenario is that the temperature sensor isn't working.  This wouldn't necessarily cause an immediate problem, but for example, if the car really were to overheat, the sensor might fail to detect it and the high temperature warning light might not come on.  In that case, you wouldn't know to pull over and you might damage the engine.

If the same sensors control the fan or other aspects of the cooling system, then this malfunction might make the car more likely to overheat as well.

Comment: Newer Subaru models also have lights in lieu of a temp gauge.

Answer (score -1):

There's a service bulletin for replacing the thermostat  should be covered under warranty

Comment: Do you have a reference to the service bulletin? Maybe the number or a link to the bulletin itself?

Comment: Honda service bulletin number 13-044 may want to call local Honda dealer for warranty repair as I stated before!